# What is an alternative to escaped unicode localized property files in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, localization

If I want my localized property file to have the character in native language such as 嗨 instead of the Escaped Unicode \u55e8 (obtained using native2ascii),

Currently I am reading the property file using ResourceBundle.getBundle by passing in the locale. If I don't save the propertyfiles in escaped unicode, what shows up in the browser is garbage.

Is there a way to make this work without escaped unicode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using ResourceBundle, I used MessageSource. Then I read the value of string using MessageSource.getMessage(String var1, Object[] var2, Locale var3)

If I do that, I don't need to modify my property files with escaped unicode.